# SQL ORDER BY query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to have my table,`rcarddet`, ordered by "SDNO" (not primary key) in ascending order with the exception of "0". So it should turn out to be like:

```
1
1 
2
.
.
10
0
0
```

My query now is:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `rcarddet` 
 WHERE `RDATE` = '2011-05-25' 
   AND `RCNO` = '1' 
   AND `PLACE` = 'H' 
   AND `SDNO` != 0 
ORDER BY `rcarddet`.`SDNO` ASC;
```

Comment: You could do something like this (untested, obviously, I don't know the specifics of your situation... or if this type of thing even works.. but you can toy with it.) This should set everything to zero as the maximum value of SDNO and therefore put them at the end
`SELECT *,IF(SDNO = 0, max(SDNO), SNDO) as order, FROM rcarddet WHERE RDATE = '2011-05-25' and RCNO = '1'and PLACE = 'H' and SDNO != 0 ORDER BY order ASC;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `rcarddet` 
 WHERE `RDATE` = '2011-05-25' 
   AND `RCNO` = '1' 
   AND `PLACE` = 'H' 
ORDER BY
  `SDNO` = 0,
  `SDNO`;
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way

```
  SELECT * FROM rcarddet   
   WHERE RDATE = '2011-05-25' and RCNO = '1'and PLACE = 'H'  
ORDER BY CASE  
           WHEN rcarddet.SDNO  = 0 THEN [max_number_for_the_type_of_SDNO]  
           ELSE rcarddet.SDNO   
         END ASC
```

Comment: Hi MOG Ponies, 

Can you roughly explain to me what is [max_number_for_the_type_of_SDNO] for? 
I can understand all but that.
Sorry for the troubles.

Comment: Look up SDNO's type in the following table and use the maximum value.  For example, if SDNO is an INT, use 2147483647.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: But this won't be guaranteed to work if an `SDNO` field happens to naturally hold the max value for its type.